# How to make field unique with other models

Tags: python, django

I have 3 different models, and they all have **index** field (small positive integer number). How to make them unique with each other?

I was trying to override save model in models.py, and this is work pretty good, except *ValidationError* exception. It redirect me to the error page, and if i turn Debug=False, it will nothing show me at all, just "error 500" or something like that.
It would be great if this validation show message in admin's page, without refreshing.

Maybe someone know how to validate this properly, or how to make this in other way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a fourth model with foreign keys to  the three models and using unique_together meta class attribute in the fourth model ?
Example only ! This is not legit django code.

```
Class Example(models.Model):
    a = models.foreignKey
    b = models.foreignKey

   Class Meta:
        unique_together = ('a', 'b')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have have some kind of business logic relation between these models. Why do not create a `parent` model with the unique key defined there ? Ie.

```
class MasterModel(models.Model):
    unique_attribute = models.CharField(unique=True)

class Child1(MasterModel):
    .... specific fields here....

class Child2(MasterModel):
    .... specific fields here....

class Child3(MasterModel):
    .... specific fields here....
```